# Linux behaviour: network route without a gateway

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, routing, iproute

I have come across a Linux system where some routes through Ethernet interfaces are configured without a gateway specified. I have always thought that routes where an interface is specified instead of a gateway is intended only for point-to-point links. This does not make sense in the case of Ethernet interfaces as Ethernet is not a point-to-point medium.

How does Linux deliver packets when they match a route through an Ethernet interface with no gateway specified? Does it broadcast an ARP request for the destination IP address from the interface? (and the unspecified gateway must act as an ARP proxy?) Does the behaviour differ in case of policy-based routing with multiple routing tables? (the second example below)

Here is an example of such a route:

```
[Gaia]# ip route list
10.25.35.0/24 dev eth3  proto routed
...

[Gaia]# cat /proc/net/route
Iface   Destination     Gateway         Flags   RefCnt  Use     Metric  Mask            MTU     Window  IRTT
eth3    0023190A        00000000        0011    0       0       0       00FFFFFF        0       0       0
...

[Gaia]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.25.35.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   UD    0      0        0 eth3
...
```

Example of such a PBR route:

```
[Gaia]# ip route list table 2
default dev eth7  proto routed
...
```

The system is running Check Point Gaia R77.30 which is based on RHEL 5.2 with Linux kernel 2.6.18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct (and you can easily check that with `tcpdump -i eth7 -n`). I have never seen that with `default`, only with networks but that probably does not make a difference. An ARP request for the destination IP address is broadcasted on that interface.

Policy routing just selects routing tables and does not affect the problem of not having a next hop defined.

Comment: Thank you, I will check it and confirm here later. Unfortunately on the system mentioned I did not catch any packet on the routes without a gateway yet.

Comment: @pabouk Were you looking for ARP packets?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an isolated network with no connections to other networks, then you don't need a gateway. The hosts communicate directly with each other, and find each other using ARP (or neighbor discovery, in the case of IPv6).

Local connections are handled like this even if you *do* have a gateway. The same mechanism is also used to locate the gateway on the network if you are communicating outside the network. A host needs to know the MAC address of the gateway host to be able to send an outgoing packet via it, so it uses ARP/ND to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Each Ethernet network interface will have a route specified to the network segment that is local to itself. Without gateways you should always be able to contact hosts on your local network segments and each NIC connects to a local network.

To contact hosts beyond your local networks you need to route your traffic via a gateway. At the gateway (router), either the destination IP is local to itself or it gets forwarded to a further router and so on.

> How does Linux deliver packets when they match a route through an Ethernet interface with no gateway specified?

Your question is somewhat unclear to me:

- Do you mean the destination of the packets are within the interface's local network (you did say the route "matched")? Then as you suggest it uses ARP to locate the device and issues ethernet frames towards it - there is no routing involved in this case, you can contact the host directly because it is local to you;
- Do you mean the destination is not on the local segment? Then routing does not occur, the packet is dropped because your routing table is unable to work out where it needs to send the packet to (regardless of which interfaces or local networks you have);

Gateways are defined to enable routing of packets that are not local to your host.